# Joining two multi lined strings

Tags: python, string, join

I am trying to concatenate data that is across multiple lines. I won't muddy the waters by telling you where this data is from, but it is in the form of a string and a sample might be something like this:

```
aaa  +  bbb  =  aaabbb
aaa  +  bbb  =  aaabbb
aaa  +  bbb  =  aaabbb
```

I've done some simple demonstration code below:

```
a = "next\nnext\nnext"
b = "text\ntext\ntext"

c = a,b
c = ','.join(c[0:2])

print c
```

With an intended output of:

```
next,text
next,text
next,text
```

But what I am getting printed looks like this:

```
next
next
next,text
text
text
```

I'm not sure if I have just picked a bad method of building some multi line code or my code isn't right, but either way, could someone suggest a way to get the desired output format of:

```
aaabbb
aaabbb
aaabbb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
a = "next\nnext\nnext"
b = "text\ntext\ntext"
print("\n".join([",".join(x) for x in zip(a.split(),b.split()))])
next,text
next,text
next,text
```

split on new line, zip then rejoin.

```
# ele 0 from a is grouped with  ele 0 from b etc..
In [15]: zip(a.split(),b.split()) 
Out[15]: [('next', 'text'), ('next', 'text'), ('next', 'text')]
# then we rejoin as one string the elements in the  tuples ('next', 'text') ->  'next,text'
In [18]: [",".join(x) for x in zip(a.split(),b.split())] 
Out[18]: ['next,text', 'next,text', 'next,text']
```

Comment: hello again. thanks for replying. i will have a look at this tomorrow and see if i can integrate it with my real code. in your example, i am fine with the top bit of code, but could you explain to me what the bottom bit is doing? for example i'm not sure what 'In[15]:' does. thanks

Comment: they are just line numbers from my ipython shell, they have no bearing on the code